# What are all $L^pL^q$ estimates for the heat equation (with gain of derivatives)?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, heat-equation

**The heat equation and the heat kernel.**

Consider the heat equation on $\mathbb R$:
$$ \left\{\begin{aligned}u_t-\Delta u&=f\\u(0,x)&=0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb R. \end{aligned}\right. $$
It is well-known that under suitable hypotheses there exists a unique solution $u$ given by the Duhamel formula (see below). So, we consider the operator $\Gamma:=(\partial_t-\Delta)^{-1} $ which maps $f$ to the solution $u$, that is, $u=\Gamma f$. Given the heat kernel
$$ G(t,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}, $$
one can show that $u$ is given as a space-time convolution between $G$ and $f$:
$$ u(t,x)=\left(\Gamma f\right)(t,x)=\int_0^\infty\int_{\mathbb R^d} G(t-s,x-y)f(s,y)\,\,dyds. $$

---

**The problem.**

> **Problem.** Given $s\in[0,2]$, find all quadruples $(p,q,r,\sigma)$ such that the
> following estimate holds for all test functions $f\in\mathcal
>  D((0,\infty)\times\mathbb R)$: $$ \||\partial_x|^s\Gamma f
>  \|_{L^rL^\sigma}\leq C\|f\|_{L^pL^q}. \qquad (1)$$

The norm in the space $L^pL^q$ is given by
$$ \|f\|_{L^pL^q}^p:=\int_0^\infty\|f(s,\cdot)\|^p_{L^q}ds, $$
so it's the classical mixed $L^p-L^q$ norm in which you take first the $L^q$ norm in the $x$ variable and then the $L^p$ norm in the $t$ variable. The fractional derivative $|\partial_x|^s$ is defined via the Fourier transform.

Basically, the problem is to find all the 'Strichartz estimates' of the heat equation with fractional gain of derivatives. Note that this is **not** about the fractional heat equation: we simply want to prove estimates on the derivatives of the solution to the classical heat equation.

---

**Considerations and known estimates.**

By scaling considerations, one immediately finds that the coefficients must satisfy
$$ \left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1/2}{\sigma}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1/2}{q}\right)-1+\frac{s}{2}. \qquad (2)$$
Thus, in what follows I will always assume $(2)$. I will also assume $p\leq r$ and $q\leq\sigma$ (essentially because convolution with a given function maps $L^p$ to $L^q$ with $q\geq p$).

Preliminarly, I state without proof the following estimates for the heat kernel:
$$ \||\partial_x|^sG(t,\cdot)\|_{L_x^p}\lesssim |t|^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+s)+\frac{1}{2p}}, \quad s\geq 0,\,\,1\leq p\leq \infty. \qquad (3)$$

What I already know is the following:

1. The estimate holds in the cases
   $$ s\in\{0,1\},\quad 1\leq q\leq \sigma\leq \infty,\quad 1<p<r<\infty. $$
   This follows from a direct use of the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality and the estimates $(3)$ for $s=0$ and $s=1$ (see [this book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311233584_Harmonic_analysis_method_for_nonlinear_evolution_equations_I)).
2. This is not in the book, but with the same proof, using the full range of estimates $(3)$, one covers all the cases $s\in[0,2)$ with the same conditions on $p,q,r,\sigma$ as above.
3. The estimates hold in the case $(r,\sigma)=(\infty,2)$ with $1\leq q\leq 2$. This follows by integrating the heat equation against $u$ and perform standard energy estimates.

What is left is a lot of endpoint cases (most prominently, $s=2$, $p=r$, $p=1$, and $r=\infty$).

---

**Finally, my question.**

My question is about the case $r=\infty$, $1<\sigma<\infty$ and $s\in(0,2)$. It seems that energy estimates do not help for the full range of exponents $(p,q)$ and work only for certain values of $\sigma$ anyway. Do you know a way to cover all cases? I am reasonably sure that one can invert the roles of $x$ and $t$ and use Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev, but that would work only for $p\leq q$.

I am especially interested in the case $(r,\sigma)=(\infty,2)$, $q=2$ for $s\in(0,2)$ (which would basically cover all other cases $(p,q)$ by Sobolev embedding), or even $q<2$ if the case $q=2$ is too hard. Even the case $s=1$ is not clear to me at the moment, except when $(p,q)=(2,2)$.

Besides my specific question, it would be nice to collect some references that address the estimate in all known ranges of exponents (unless you can think of a paper which treats all these estimates at once, which would be very appreciated). So, if you have a reference for any of the remaining ranges of exponents, even for higher dimensions, that would be very appreciated.

---

**Related posts and references:**

- [A previous post with a similar question (basically the case $s=0$)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270405/strichartz-estimates-for-the-heat-equation)
- [Something about the case $s=2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218687/mixed-norm-estimate-for-the-heat-equation)

Comment: What you are looking for, is called a mixed derivative estimate derived from the $\mathrm{L}^q$-maximal regularity for the (negative)-Laplacian acting on $\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

You can probably use the **Theorem 3.1** from the recent paper by **Brandolese** and **Monniaux**, https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02450v2. This in combination with vector-valued Sobolev embeddings (in time) for homogeneous Sobolev spaces, you can found in this paper (**Proposition 3.4**, Check also **Section 3.2**) : https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.09862, should give you the desired result.

Comment: For some reasons, $r=+\infty$ arise from the trace theory in evolution equations. The best you can expect in general is not an $\mathrm{L}^\sigma$-space w.r.t the space variable, but a (homogeneous) Besov space. The case of Lebesgue spaces would follow from Sobolev-Lebesgue embeddings for Besov spaces.

Note that we can prove
$$\lVert u \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^\infty(\dot{\mathrm{H}}^s)}\leqslant C \lVert f \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{s-1})}\leqslant C' \lVert f \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2({\mathrm{L}}^{p})}$$
for $1/p=1/2 - (s-1)/n$, $s\in(-n/2,1]$, and this somehow optimal.

Comment: Wow, thank you :) I guess the last inequality is reversed, but I get what you say.

Comment: Since $s-1$ is negative, the last inequality is actually the good one. In Sobolev embeddings the homogeneous norm with the higher regularity (here $0$, the $\mathrm{L}^p$-norm) control the one with the lower regularity  (here $s-1$, the $\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{s-1}$-norm).

A last thing is that, I really want to emphasize the fact that the estimates for the cases $r\in(1,+\infty)$ and $r=+\infty$ are arising for, related, but really, different reasons.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry. Yes, that estimate is all you can obtain from the case $s=0$ and using the homogeneity/symmetry.

Comment: In fact, playing with Sobolev embeddings (in time and in space) and $\mathrm{L}^q_t(\mathrm{L}^p)$-maximal regularity estimates, one should be able to prove many variants of such estimates estimates beyond the pure $\mathrm{L}^2$ case.